# Encrypt a file with a password to send via email in python

Tags: python, email, encryption

Here is what I need to do in python:
Take a CSV from a saved location. Encrypt it. Send it via email.
 
We have a report that creates a csv every week and it needs to get emailed to someone. When they open the attachment from their email, it needs to ask them to input a predetermined password before they can view the csv contents.

I know how to send email with attachments using the smtp and mime modules.
I don't really know much about encryption but most of my searches turn up for files that are going to also be DEcrypted by python, or for encrypting passwords themselves.

Is asking for password upon opening a .csv file possible? Are there any resources out there for tutorials on this?

Comment: Could you just encrypt the email with OpenPGP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an unsophisticated approach, you could zip the csv file that requires a password to unzip. This is a simple command line option (to the zip utility) that you could call from Python, then attach the resulting file. This wouldn't give you the best encryption, but may serve your purpose. [See this link on using stronger encryption with zip archives.](http://www.howtogeek.com/203590/how-to-create-secure-encrypted-zip-or-7z-archives-on-any-operating-system/)

Comment: I'm in windows 7, it looks like the only way to zip from command line is with third party software, which isn't an option for me.